# What does "mode" attribute do?

Tags: gcc, gcc-attribute

I have read [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes) but I am not able to understand it. What does following typedefs do? What is/should be size of a variable of type word/pointer/_Unwind_Word on a 8/16/32/64 bit architecture?

```
typedef unsigned int word __attribute__((mode(word)));
typedef unsigned int pointer __attribute__((mode(pointer)));
```

([full source](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/emutls.c;h=0fea1f10bfabb5b08c85ff628d5fe57079881650;hb=HEAD), lines 33–34)

```
typedef unsigned _Unwind_Word __attribute__((__mode__(__unwind_word__)));
typedef signed _Unwind_Sword __attribute__((__mode__(__unwind_word__)));
```

([full source](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libgcc/unwind-generic.h;h=6e6987fe3f9a284d9d37154a4f1331709abce867;hb=HEAD), lines 49–50)